# How do I re-write this propositional formula in conjunctive normal form (CNF)?

Tags: propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I'm struggling with this problem -- though it would seem simple enough.  I think it's the parentheses that are getting me confused here.

I need to convert (p→(q⋁r))⋁(s↔t) to conjunctive normal form (CNF).

The possible answers are:

a. (¬p⋁q⋁r⋁¬s⋁t)⋀(¬p⋁q⋁r⋁¬t⋁s)

b. (¬p⋀q⋀r⋀¬s⋀t)⋁(¬p⋀q⋀r⋀¬t⋀s)

c. (p⋁q⋁r)⋀(s⋁t)

d. (¬p⋁q⋁r)⋀(¬s⋁t)⋀(¬p⋁q⋁r)⋀(¬t⋁s)

As a side note, this is just for a practice quiz.

Here is my work thus far:

```
(p→(q⋁r))⋁(s↔t)
=> (¬p ⋁ (q ⋁ r)) ⋁ ( (s → t) ⋀ (t → s))
=>  (¬p ⋁ (q ⋁ r)) ⋁ ( (¬s ⋁ t) ⋀ (¬t ⋁ s))
=> ((¬p⋁q) ⋀ (¬p⋁r)) ⋁ ((¬s ⋁ t)⋀(¬t ⋁ s))
```

This is where I am getting stuck - I don't understand what I'm supposed to do next. ​

Comment: You want all the $\wedge$s on the outside.  You still have some that aren't on the outside.  So continue with the distributive law...

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but it doesn't help me -- I don't understand how to continue with it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
(p\implies(q\lor r))\lor(s\iff t) \\
(\lnot p\lor(q\lor r))\lor((s\implies t) \land (t \implies s))  \\
(\lnot p\lor q\lor r)\lor((\lnot s\lor t) \land (\lnot t \lor s))  \\
((\lnot p\lor q\lor r)\lor (\lnot s\lor t)) \land ((\lnot p\lor q\lor r)\lor (\lnot t \lor s))  \\
(\lnot p\lor q\lor r\lor \lnot s\lor t) \land (\lnot p\lor q\lor r\lor \lnot t \lor s)  \\
$$